# Why aren't all $n$-categories equivalent to a strict one?

Tags: category-theory, soft-question, intuition, higher-category-theory

Every 2-category is equivalent to a strict 2-category. So naively it would be expected that every n-category is equivalent to a strict one. But this is false. Is there an easy explanation or intuition for this?

While [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1527655/957774) is related, it doesn't really provide any intuition for this, and the examples require a lot of background. Is there an easier, even if less rigorous explanation?

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527655/smallest-3-category-not-equivalent-to-a-strict-3-category?rq=1